# Django Creating a custom user model

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, rest

Hello i am trying to create a custom user model (that inherit from User) to make the user to  put their email rather than usernames, and i am getting an error in settings.py, I have no idea about `CustomUser` app, but i am trying to figure out if we can include this as an app inside settings.py, the code and traceback:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """
    Custom user model manager where email is the unique identifiers
    for authentication instead of usernames.
    """
    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('The Email must be set'))
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password.
        """
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_staff=True.'))
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.'))
        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)


class Ticket(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    desc = models.TextField(max_length=99999)

class RespondToTicket(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=999)
    respond = models.TextField(max_length=999999)

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = email
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    objects = CustomUserManager()
```

the error i am getting when i am running the web server:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ghazi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py", line 156, in get_user_model
    return django_apps.get_model(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, require_ready=False)
  File "C:\Users\ghazi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 205, in get_model
    app_config = self.get_app_config(app_label)
  File "C:\Users\ghazi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 162, in get_app_config
    raise LookupError(message)
LookupError: No installed app with label 'users'.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ghazi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\ghazi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ghazi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ghazi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\ghazi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 76, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\ghazi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\ghazi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ghazi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\ghazi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 122, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "C:\Users\ghazi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\apps.py", line 24, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "C:\Users\ghazi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\__init__.py", line 26, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "C:\Users\ghazi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 47, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "C:\Users\ghazi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\ghazi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\admin.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import (
  File "C:\Users\ghazi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\forms.py", line 20, in <module>
    UserModel = get_user_model()
  File "C:\Users\ghazi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py", line 160, in get_user_model
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'users.CustomUser' that has not been installed
```

settings.py

```
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'rest_framework',
    'main',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'backend.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'backend.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 's',
        'USER': 's',
        'PASSWORD': '0000',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': 'prt',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = False


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser'
```

Comment: Keep in mind that if you have an app which contains models, you must add it to settings.py as an installed app. Have you tried adding `'users'` to `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: This line `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser' assume that you have an app named `users` .  Folow @Nick ODell advice

Comment: @NickODell @Rvector 
it seems like i am getting error :
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'users'`, am i supposed to import something?

Comment: @Ghazi What directory is the models.py file you posted located in?

Comment: @NickODell the directory is called `main` (basically the django app name), i tried `main.users`, but that failed with the same error

Comment: If your model file is in `main`, then you need to set `AUTH_USER_MODEL` to `main.CustomUser`.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).